# lua dofile "no such file or directory" in Windows

Tags: windows, lua

I have the Programming in Lua book and I downloaded the batteries included lua for Windows.

One of the first examples is a function that's saved in a file called lib1.lua.  I created this function in the SciTE text editor and saved the file in the directory on my C: drive that contains lua.exe.

But when I type dofile("lib1.lua") in the lua interpreter I get a "no such file or directory".  I've looked in several websites and they mention changing the path variable, but they don't say how.  Is this a variable in Windows?  Or a lua variable somewhere in one of the directories?

Help?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know anything about lua, but have you tried `dofile("C:\lib1.lua")` (might need to be a double backslash)

Comment: What's the path where you started the Lua interpreter?

Comment: Use full filespec `dofile("C:\\path\\to\\lib1.lua")` or place your file in the "current directory".

Answer (score 6):

You need to put `lib1.lua` into the current folder where the script is being executed or use the absolute path `dofile([[c:\path\lib1.lua]])`. In the case of paths on Windows it's better to use `[[]]` as string separators as this allows you to not use slash escaping and paths look more "natural".